# Natural Lie algebra representation on function space

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

> There is natural Lie group representation of $GL(n)$ on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ given by
>   \begin{align}
> \rho: GL(n) &  \rightarrow \text{End}(C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)) \\
> A & \rightarrow \left( \rho(A):f \rightarrow f\circ A^{-1} \right)
> \end{align}
>   What is the associated lie algebra representation?

It should be tangent map of $\rho$ at unit element. So take path $A(t)$ in $GL(n)$, that $A(0)=I$, $A'(0)= X$. And start differentiating
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0} f(A^{-1}(t)x) = -f'(x)Xx
$$

This gives me $\rho^*(X)(f(x)) = - f'(x)Xx$. But than $\rho([X,Y]) \neq [\rho(X),\rho(Y)]$ because $\rho([X,Y])(f)$ would contain first derivatives of $f$ but $[\rho(X),\rho(Y)](f)$ would contain second derivatives of $f$.

---

I have one more question. Do I get into the trouble when I consider representation on $C(\mathbb R^n)$(i.e. dropping the smoothness)? Is it still sensible to ask for Lie algebra representation?

---

Ok based on the encouragement from answer, that I got it right. I went through the calculation. Here it is:

\begin{align}
\rho(X)(f(x)) &= - (\partial_i f(x)) X_{ij} x_j \\
\rho(Y)\rho(X)(f(x)) &= \partial_k ((\partial_i f(x)) X_{ij} x_j) Y_{kl}x_l  \\
&= (\partial_k \partial_i f(x)) X_{ij} Y_{kl} x_j x_l + (\partial_i f(x)) X_{ik} Y_{kl} x_l \\
\rho(X)\rho(Y)(f(x)) &=  (\partial_k \partial_i f(x)) Y_{ij} X_{kl} x_j x_l + (\partial_i f(x)) Y_{ik} X_{kl} x_l \\
&=  (\partial_k \partial_i f(x)) X_{ij} Y_{kl} x_j x_l + (\partial_i f(x)) Y_{ik} X_{kl} x_l
\end{align}

As you can see those second order term in $\rho(X)\rho(Y)(f(x))$ and $\rho(Y)\rho(X)(f(x))$ are the same and cancel out in the commutator $[\rho(X),\rho(Y)]$.

I had to use index notation in the proof because it seamed to me as the most reasonable choice, but still I do not like it. Another option is to write down the second order term as 
$$
(\partial_k \partial_i f(x)) Y_{ij} X_{kl} x_j x_l = x^T Y^T f''(x) X x
$$
But this is not useful when I would do third derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation is correct, but you were too pessimistic about the continuation: the second derivative terms in the bracket of $\rho(X)$ and $\rho(Y)$ *cancel*.

It becomes less reasonable to ask for a Lie algebra repn on not-smooth functions, since natural Lie algebra repns are differential operators. Nevertheless, once you start down that path, if you go all the way to the action on *distributions* and distributional derivatives, things become sensible again.

Comment: I went through the calculation and it works and the idea with distributions seams sensible. Thanks!